# How an HTTP Injection bypass a firewall

Tags: http, networking, https, firewall

For a while now many apps/application in almost all platforms (example [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.injector) on android) that can be used to "inject a certain url or text" (usually of that one allowed address) to an blocked outgoing connection and magically bypass a firewall.

I have intercepted one of these connections with fiddler but cant seem to see the difference between an injected an non injected connection especially HTTPS. how to they fool ISPs? what does it take to forge connection like those?

Comment: The tool you linked to uses SSH tunnels to bypass the firewall.  For example if you are behind a firewall that blocks traffic to stackoverflow.com, you could get around this restriction by establishing an encrypted tunnel to a server than can access stackoverflow.com.  Then you ask that server to request the site for you, it does so and passes you back the result.  It is like if there is a restaurant who will not serve you, and you ask your friend to go in and buy a sandwich for you.  Here is a diagram.  http://calebmadrigal.com/images/ssh_tunnel.png

Comment: Thanks you may also note that the app allow you to define your own SSH server and also your own url to inject. The url i am injecting is usually any of those website my ISP allows me to browse for free, the my own ssh server located elsewhere. Are you saying allowed site are active proxies on there site allowing me to access my SSH server?

Comment: @mikey I mean if only the ssh server is required why do i have to give the ul too

Comment: What are you trying to learn how to do?  Injection and SSH tunnels are generally 2 different things, they can be used together but do not need to be coupled.

Comment: I want to learn injection.. Because it seems the one    able to penetrate the firewall

Comment: In what direction do you want to penetrate a firewall?  Are you trying to break out of one, or into one?

Comment: Out of one, like tricking it to think i am connecting to an allowedwebsite.com

Comment: That generally is a "web filter", probably not a "firewall".  A well designed web filter will not be tricked by HTTP injection, nor would a firewall.  https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131203132929AAXRTeg  -- using an SSH tunnel would be a better approach.  You could even use a translation site like https://translate.google.com/ , enter the URL of a non-allowed site and translate it to another language.  This will fetch the content and it will look like you're communicating only with Google.  Google probably has restrictions on what sorts of sites you can translate so..